# How to remove all Attributes by attribute name starts with

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to remove all the attributes that attribute name starts with 'data-val' in the fields that has a class 'read-only-state'

```
 jQuery("[data-val^='tr']" )
```

This will give attribute 'data-val' value that starts with 'tr'

> But i need to **remove all the attributes that starts with
>   'data-val'** in the matched elements.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use vanilla javascript's `attributes` for this:

```
$('.read-only-state').each(function() {
   // get the native attributes object
   var attrs = this.attributes;
   var toRemove = [];
   // cache the jquery object containing the element for better performance
   var element = $(this);

   // iterate the attributes
   for (attr in attrs) {
     if (typeof attrs[attr] === 'object' && 
         typeof attrs[attr].name === 'string' && 
         (/^data-val/).test(attrs[attr].name)) {
       // Unfortunately, we can not call removeAttr directly in here, since it
       // hurts the iteration.
       toRemove.push(attrs[attr].name);
     }
   }

   for (var i = 0; i < toRemove.length; i++) {
     element.removeAttr(toRemove[i]);
   }
});
```

Comment: attrs.hasOwnProperty(attr) Object doesn't support this property or method Error

Comment: No. Even i checked in chrome by inspecting elements. It still shows data-val and other data-val-req, etc attributes

Comment: weird, it works for me in chrome, firefox, ie. How does your html look like?

Comment: Ok, there was a problem with the `removeAttr` being called during an iteration. The update should fix this. I tried `$('<input data-val-length="The field Id must be a string with a maximum length of 50." data-val-required=" Id is required" id="FacilityID" name="ID" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="C0B" class="read-only-state valid"/>').prependTo('body');` and then the code. It successfully removed all attributes in all browsers.

Comment: Awesome. Its great. Working in IE 7 too :)