# plain js to select element by attribute name starts with

Tags: javascript, regex, selector, built-in

## Context :

- HTML

  ```
   <div ng-me=""></div>
   <div ng-you=""></div>
    <p ng-you=""></p>
  ```

I want to select all elements which has attribute name starts with `ng-`.

---

Using jQuery , the following links are the closest threads to  this issue :

1. [jQuery - How to select value by attribute name starts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657398/jquery-how-to-select-value-by-attribute-name-starts-with) .
2. [How to remove all Attributes by attribute name starts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731439/how-to-remove-all-attributes-by-attribute-name-starts-with) .

However ,the first uses jQuery , and the second resolves **removing** issue of **already selected elements** NOT  **selection** .

I try this :

```
document.querySelectorAll('[ng-*]')
```

And it does not work , but rather, it throws error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here I use querySelectorAll to get all objects that I want to check.

Then I look at the attributes collection of each returned object

ES6+

```js
const attrStartsWith = (sel,str) => [...document.querySelectorAll(sel)]
  .filter(ele => [...ele.attributes]
    .filter(({name}) => name.startsWith(str))
    .length>0
  )

console.log(attrStartsWith("*","ng")); // all
console.log(attrStartsWith("div","ng")); // divs
```

```html
<div ng-a="a">a</div>
<div ng-b="b">b</div>
<p ng-c="c">c</p>
```

ES5 and lower

```js
function attrStartsWith(sel,str) {
  var el = document.querySelectorAll(sel), res=[];
  
  for (var i = 0, n=el.length; i < n; i++){
    for (var j=0;j<el[i].attributes.length;j++) {
      if (el[i].attributes[j].name.indexOf(str)==0) {
        res.push(el[i]); 
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(attrStartsWith("*","ng")); // all
console.log(attrStartsWith("div","ng")); // divs
```

```html
<div ng-a="a">a</div>
<div ng-b="b">b</div>
<p ng-c="c">c</p>
```

Comment: What about if our tag is `p`, `a` .. anytag except `div`. Something hyperdynamic

Comment: Oh .. I got now your anser.. it seems tht u edit it .. That's why i put my answer  which is closest to your answer adter editing .. Thus, You deserve

Comment: I changed my code to a function in reply to your question 3 hours ago :)

Comment: Hi @mplungjan , I really have the same question: who did votedown ? and why?

Answer (score 4):

## ES6 solution :

```
const attrStartsWith = (prefix) =>
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'))
   .filter(
      (e) => Array.from(e.attributes).filter(
        ({name, value}) => name.startsWith(prefix)).length
   )
```

Then :

```
attrStartsWith('ng-') // return an array of HTML elements which  have attributes name starts with "ng-"
```

#### versions of 2017-12-02

```
const queryByAttrNameStartsWith = (contextualSelector = '*') => {
  const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(contextualSelector));
  return (prefix) =>
    elements.filter(e =>
      Array.from(e.attributes).find(({ name, value }) =>
        name.startsWith(prefix)
      )
    );
};
//then
queryByAttrNameStartsWith('*')('data-'); // all elements that have attribute name that starts with 'data-'
queryByAttrNameStartsWith('div')('ng-'); // ony DIV elements that have attribute name that starts with 'ng-'
//.. so on
```

or :

```
NodeList.prototype.filterByAttrNameStartsWith = function(prefix) {
  return Array.from(this).filter(e =>
    Array.from(e.attributes).find(({ name, value }) => name.startsWith(prefix))
  );
};
//then
document.querySelectorAll('*')
 .filterByAttrNameStartsWith('data-'); // all elements that have attribute name that starts with 'data-'
document.querySelectorAll('div')
 .filterByAttrNameStartsWith('ng-'); // ony DIV elements that have attribute name that starts with 'ng-'
//.. so on
```

Comment: yeah ! but it is non-functional requirements for this issue, Just it make live easy (easy reading code , easy maintain ,... so on)

Comment: Quite elegant version

Answer (score 2):

So I combined the efforts of gavgrif and mplungjan with what I made already:

HTML:

```
 <div ng-me="">1</div>
 <div ng-you="">2</div>
 <div not-me="">3</div>
 <div ng-yes="">4</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ng-class {
    background-color: red;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var list = [];

// Grab all elements on the page and check them for attributes
for (var i = 0, n = el.length; i < n; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < el[i].attributes.length; j++) {
        // If match, push into seperate array
        if (el[i].attributes[j].name.indexOf("ng") == 0)       
            list.push(el[i]);
     }
}

// Add a custom class to these elements
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].classList.add('ng-class');
}
```

[Codepen example here](http://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/mAJLda)

Comment: Your solution now is better than mine indeed, especially after the edit. (cleaner as well). fwiw: I upvoted it, and learned from it.

Answer (score 0):

Necromancing.

## ES 5 solution :

```
    function findElementsWithArributePrefix(selector, prefix)
    {
        return [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).filter(function (e)
        {
            return [].slice.call(e.attributes).filter(
                function (attr)
                {
                    return attr.name.startsWith(prefix);
                }
            ).length;
        });
    }
```

Then :

```
console.log("prfx", findElementsWithArributePrefix("*", "ng-"));
```

Comment: @mplungjan: Nope, if you had, that was somebody else.

Answer (score -1):

div [^="ng-"] should do it for you - What this does is specificy all elements that have attributes that start with "ng-" (and in his example applies a background color)

```
*[^="ng-"] {background-color:red}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `* [^="ng-"]` selector be better? We don't know if OP has other elements beside `<div>`

Comment: Also, this doesn't work, since it doesn't target the name of the attribute, only the value.

Comment: As @ Roberrrt says - I am incorrect - this is only targets the value of the attribute - not the name. I posted it - thought I was very clever then actually read up on selectors based on attribute and realised I am not very clever. I will leave the post up because it helpful for the OP and it may allow others to start thinking of specific slecectors based on attribute content. Thanks

Comment: This is css selector not accepted by `document.querySelectorAll`